# Call list of methods on object in sequence, piping the methods?

Tags: ruby, method-chaining

I want to do the following:

```
 object.method1.method2.method3.method4
```

except that all methods are in one array. So, in an example:

```
 object = 1
 methods = %W(to_s split shift)
 # should somehow do 1.to_s.split.shift
```

How can I call the `methods` in sequence on object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do as below using [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

```
object = 1
%w(to_s split shift).inject(object,:send) # => "1"
```